# How to stop a PHP exec from web interface

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Lets say for example we have the following index.php. Also we assume that this PHP code will never end execution and it will run for ever and ever. I want a way to cancel this PHP excution from an interface from this page. An action triggered by the user seeing this website. Not from inside the PHP script which runs on the web-server.

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Main</title>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="#" class="button">Cancel PHP execution</a>

    <?php
    // magic that takes time
    ?>

</body>
</html>
```

How can i stop php execution from a button or an event that happens client side. I am open to all kind of solutions ajax, js...

The algorithm does heavy calculations which have time complexity of !n where I don't want to check in that php logic every time if to exit because I don't know where the execution will be and also i do not know which part is going to take more time, that is, the command to stop my routine it's async, pratically.

Comment: You can flush the buffer that not the problem. @Don'tPanic

Comment: True, good point.

Comment: Unless you have the `ignore_user_abort` setting enabled in `php.ini`, the script will be aborted if the user closes the window. I don't think there's a way to do it on a button push.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use a limitless 'magic', you will need some kind of loop. Inside of loop put a flag, like:

```
while (1==1) {
  if ($flag){
     break;
  }
}
```

And let the user fill that flag with $_GET or $_POST.

PS: I strongly advise you to avoid those loops routines, php doesn't work well with them because it's a script, risky to break the browser with an overload. Btw, just to refresh the page with some submit if you rely on PHP only will 'break' you script execution (if the page doesn't break until that). To use continuous routines into web the main approach it's with javascript (and if you need to store something or bring any kind of information, adding AJAX with it).

EDIT: Well, what you need then it's using AJAX with callbacks to validate each process from your routine/calculations (likable, because you can store the last calc process, using some cache to improve the time of next calculation - if the algorithm is so heavy) or just stop the ajax call when user click in some button or stuff:

```
var strongcalcs = $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'magic.php',
    success: function(result){}
});
```

In your PHP file:

```
<?php
// magic that takes time
?>
```

Then you can abort the request:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Main</title>
</head>
<body>
    <button class="button">Cancel PHP execution</button>

</body>
</html>
<script>
$('button').on('click', function(){
   strongcalcs.abort();
});
</script>
```

FINAL:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Main</title>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="cancel" class="button">Cancel PHP execution</button>

    <script language="javascript">

    var strongcalcs = $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'execute.php',
        success: function(result){
            alert(result);
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("ABORT!");
        }
    });

    $('#cancel').click(function () {
        strongcalcs.abort();

    });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Imagine that i am doing heavy calculations which have time complexity of !n i don't want to check in that php logic every time if to exit because i don't know where the execution will be and also i do not know which part is going to take more time. To check a variable.

Comment: i will try something like that i will get back to you in a bit.